# Implications for large sums of roots of unity

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have some coefficients $(a_n)_{n \leq N} \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $a_n \geq 0$ and their average value is one, i.e. $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n \leq N} a_n = 1$. Suppose that
$$ \Bigl| \sum_{n \leq N} a_n e(n/N) \Bigr| > N^{\varepsilon}, $$
where $e(x):= e^{2\pi i x}$. I want to make some deductions about the coefficients $(a_n)$. A simple example is that the largest $a_n$ must be $\geq 1$, which follows purely from the average result and the pigeonhole principle. We can't improve on this much using the above inequality, since it's possible to have $a_n = 2$ for $n \leq N/2$, $a_n = 0$ otherwise, and the sum is $\gg N$. However, such an example imparts a lot of structure on the coefficients.

Deriving a quantitative statement about the structure of $a_n$ would be very useful. Any references to where an inverse problem of this type has been studied before would also be greatly appreciated. Even a statement like there must be an $a_n$ larger than $1 + f(N, \varepsilon)$ may be of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what range of $\epsilon$ you are interested in. If the exponential sum is near its max possible size ($> \delta N$) then you are saying that your sequence correlates with an exponential character $e(\cdot)$ and you can get a density increment on a sub-progression (al la the standard density increment proof of Roth's theorem). If you further have that the sum correlates with a large number of characters then you deduce some further additive structure (see for instance, [Additive combinatorics and large Fourier coefficients](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36653/additive-combinatorics-and-large-fourier-coefficients) and [A question regarding Bourgain's paper on $\Lambda(p)$-subsets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330747/a-question-regarding-bourgains-paper-on-lambdap-subsets?noredirect=1&lq=1)) for $\epsilon \geq 1/2$. Generic coefficients (such as randomly chosen sequences of 0's and 1's) will give a sequence where your sum is near $N^{1/2}$, so you can't say much below that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ideally, I'd have any $\varepsilon > 0$, but $1/2$ may suffice. As far as I'm aware, in the case of generic coefficients, this sum is only large (with decent probably, say) if they have a fairly high variance, which would be of significance. I've clarified my question a little.

Comment: I think your revised question is still asking for too much. If you just let $a_n=1$ for, say, $1\leq n \leq N/4$ and 0 otherwise, then the exponential sum will be $\gg N$ but no coefficient will be greater than $1$.

Comment: Your correct when you point out that a statement that "this will hold for random choices of coefficients" is a probabilistic statement, which occurs with high probability. But the implication of this is that whatever structure theorem you hope to achieve will  have to hold for random coefficients, which means it probably isn't going to tell you very much about $a_n$.

Comment: This is true, the point I was trying to make is that if you use the probabilistic method and satisfy these conditions then your coefficients need to have fairly large variance. In your example (which, when scaled, is $a_n = 4$ for $n \leq N/4$ and $0$ otherwise) this is also the case, so I believe the last line of my question may be possible for some very small function $f(N, \varepsilon)$.